How to filter nested JSON array for conditions and return only one value from the first result of filter using Javascript (for Google Sheets)?
I am using the TMDB api to fetch data about a movie into a Google Sheet. This Google Sheet was reworked from Reddit user 6745408's "MediaSheet 3.0". The sheet uses a Javascript-based script. I've been able to extract values for keys that weren't in the original script/sheet by following the patterns/code used in the original script. However, I don't know how to do the following:
There are multiple arrays nested within the "results" key. Each array nested under "result" is a video associated with this movie title. What I want returned into the Google Sheet is the url ending which is ("key"). However I only want one video url / "key" returned into the Google Sheet, I want the script to filter the "results" array for videos that have the values ("site": "YouTube") and also ("type": "trailer) OR ("type": "teaser") and then from there, return the first result from the filter and return the ("key") of that video.
This is the JSON data I am trying to parse from the TMDB api:
{
  "id": 290098,
  "results": [
    {
      "iso_639_1": "en",
      "iso_3166_1": "US",
      "name": "In the Projection Booth - Park Chan-wook, director of The Handmaiden (contains spoilers)",
      "key": "P8g8QJk96M4",
      "site": "YouTube",
      "size": 1080,
      "type": "Featurette",
      "official": true,
      "published_at": "2017-04-14T08:30:01.000Z",
      "id": "65be6283902012012fc9a5a7"
    },
    {
      "iso_639_1": "en",
      "iso_3166_1": "US",
      "name": "UK Promo",
      "key": "xX7HsdfIYGw",
      "site": "YouTube",
      "size": 1080,
      "type": "Teaser",
      "official": true,
      "published_at": "2017-03-31T16:51:17.000Z",
      "id": "65be628efc6538017cea4ee3"
    },
    {
      "iso_639_1": "en",
      "iso_3166_1": "US",
      "name": "UK Trailer",
      "key": "wYsdzNIcJNc",
      "site": "YouTube",
      "size": 1080,
      "type": "Trailer",
      "official": true,
      "published_at": "2017-03-09T12:54:54.000Z",
      "id": "65be625ea7e363018454330d"
    },
    {
      "iso_639_1": "en",
      "iso_3166_1": "US",
      "name": "Extended Preview",
      "key": "5bOWrDriBno",
      "site": "YouTube",
      "size": 1080,
      "type": "Clip",
      "official": true,
      "published_at": "2017-01-17T17:49:04.000Z",
      "id": "65be613143999b0184c5d86e"
    },
    {
      "iso_639_1": "en",
      "iso_3166_1": "US",
      "name": "Dress Up (Movie Clip)",
      "key": "y43Y20jdctw",
      "site": "YouTube",
      "size": 1080,
      "type": "Clip",
      "official": true,
      "published_at": "2016-10-24T21:00:04.000Z",
      "id": "65be60b512c604017c0096e5"
    },
    {
      "iso_639_1": "en",
      "iso_3166_1": "US",
      "name": "The House (Movie Clip)",
      "key": "jUP3cPWQBh4",
      "site": "YouTube",
      "size": 1080,
      "type": "Clip",
      "official": true,
      "published_at": "2016-10-24T17:44:18.000Z",
      "id": "65be60bca7e36301b7547dcd"
    },
    {
      "iso_639_1": "en",
      "iso_3166_1": "US",
      "name": "The Library (Movie Clip)",
      "key": "gvijQuKBz88",
      "site": "YouTube",
      "size": 1080,
      "type": "Clip",
      "official": true,
      "published_at": "2016-10-24T01:44:31.000Z",
      "id": "65be60c4031deb0162ee63e3"
    },
    {
      "iso_639_1": "en",
      "iso_3166_1": "US",
      "name": "The Kiss (Movie Clip)",
      "key": "6ir3_NoTJOw",
      "site": "YouTube",
      "size": 1080,
      "type": "Clip",
      "official": true,
      "published_at": "2016-10-22T17:00:18.000Z",
      "id": "65be60cca7e363013653c57c"
    },
    {
      "iso_639_1": "en",
      "iso_3166_1": "US",
      "name": "The Bath (Movie Clip)",
      "key": "O4p9o3aJGj8",
      "site": "YouTube",
      "size": 1080,
      "type": "Clip",
      "official": true,
      "published_at": "2016-10-21T17:00:08.000Z",
      "id": "65be60d443999b0163c50b39"
    },
    {
      "iso_639_1": "en",
      "iso_3166_1": "US",
      "name": "Official US Trailer",
      "key": "whldChqCsYk",
      "published_at": "2016-07-29T17:02:31.000Z",
      "site": "YouTube",
      "size": 1080,
      "type": "Trailer",
      "official": true,
      "id": "57dbf0eb925141684c008ae7"
    },
    {
      "iso_639_1": "en",
      "iso_3166_1": "US",
      "name": "Official International Trailer",
      "key": "NoyWKl0e8FI",
      "published_at": "2016-05-03T06:15:07.000Z",
      "site": "YouTube",
      "size": 1080,
      "type": "Trailer",
      "official": true,
      "id": "57dbf22b9251416905008c72"
    },
    {
      "iso_639_1": "en",
      "iso_3166_1": "US",
      "name": "Official Int'l Special Trailer",
      "key": "6sVYumzrKvs",
      "published_at": "2016-04-25T12:39:44.000Z",
      "site": "YouTube",
      "size": 1080,
      "type": "Trailer",
      "official": true,
      "id": "571e5a939251416f2c0003f0"
    }
  ]
}

This is the code I am working on in the Google Sheets app script:
function TMDBmovietrailer123(rows) {
  var tmdbKey = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('tmdbkey');
  const requests = rows.map(id => {
    return {
      url: `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${id}/videos?api_key=${tmdbKey}`,
      muteHttpExceptions: true
    }
  })
  const responses = UrlFetchApp.fetchAll(requests)
  return responses.map(request => {
    try {
      const data = JSON.parse(request.getContentText());
      const id = data.id

      return [id]
    } catch (err) {
      return ['']
    }
  })
}


I dont see any nested arrays inside result value for the data you provided. If the data is in the format as you provided, you can iterate over array items and use array filter() method. If nested, use a recursive function.

The value results is an Array of anonymous objects, and it's still possible to use filter on it, but for your use case the find method of Array is likely the best fit. This is because filter will continue through the array after finding an item whereas find will stop immediately after finding the first element.
Considering the object that contains the id + results to be a response, it could be done like this (response data minimized for readability):


const response = {
  "id": 290098,
  "results": [
    {
      "key": "P8g8QJk96M4",
      "site": "YouTube",
      "type": "Featurette"
    },
    {
      "key": "xX7HsdfIYGw",
      "site": "YouTube",
      "type": "Teaser"
    },
    {
      "key": "wYsdzNIcJNc",
      "site": "YouTube",
      "type": "Trailer"
    },
    {
      "key": "5bOWrDriBno",
      "site": "YouTube",
      "type": "Clip"
    }
  ]
}


const trailer = response.results.find((o) => (o?.site === 'YouTube') && (o?.type === 'Trailer' || o?.type === 'Teaser'))

console.log(trailer?.key || 'not found')



This could be expanded to use typeof o.<property> !== 'undefined' && o.<property> === 'value'.

No problem, it was fun :) And thank you for not abandoning your question.
